# VNC Server IS running on ::1:5901

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine

I am new to Linux. I have installed qemu-kvm when I started it shows command

```
VNC server running on `::1:5901'
```

Can any one please tell me how can I can access vnc server I have real vnc server and viewer also

Comment: I think the problem is you had not install qemu correctly。[install parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408248/first-time-running-qemu-vnc-viewer-not-open-automatically/59703667#59703667)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the shell prompts VNC server running on `::1:5901`
you can then use

```
virt-viewer vnc://localhost:5901
```

to connect the guest or you can open the remote desktop viewer (a GUI tool) to connect it by **vnc** protocol and **localhost:1**.
This works in my case, hope it will work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access you machine over vnc first thing you need to do is configure vnc to listen on all interface.
To do that enable/add vnc_listen = "0.0.0.0" in your /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf file and restart libvirtd. Now you can access you guest on yourkvmhostip:5901 through vnc.