# first time running qemu, vnc viewer not open automatically

Tags: qemu, vnc

Recently I downloaded qemu, and ran configure, make and make install.
when I run

```
qemu-system-sparc linux-0.2.img
```

I just see a message below

> VNC server running on `::1:5900'

At this state, when I open vncviewer window by typing `vncviewer :5900`, then I see the window.
The window shows the emulated screen

> Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1 build on Mar 10 2014 08:41
>   Type 'help'
>   for detailed information
>   Trying disk...
>   No valid state has been
>   set by load or init-program
>   0>

How can I make the vnc window come up automatically? and how do I supply right linux image?
when I build my linux image, I can get sImage.elf or sImage.bin which contains the file system too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing sdl-devel to my CentOS.
I reran ./configure --target-list=sparc-softmmu --enable-sdl
and did make, make install
and the problem is gone!

Comment: just in case after enabling "--enable-sdl" and you get problem, then perhaps there are other stuff to install as well, the complete writeup is here:   https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/installing-qemu/

Answer (score 1):

Coming up with a good command line for QEMU can be surprisingly challenging.
I'd still recommend using virt-manager to set up QEmu and to then take a look at the command line that it generated.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is probably that you didn't have the necessary libraries installed to build the GTK support. When you run QEMU's configure script, it will automatically include all optional features that your system has the required libraries for.

However, if you don't have libraries like GTK or SDL installed, those features will be omitted. In that case, the resulting QEMU binary will only have the basic VNC support.

**SOLUTION:**

1. To ensure that you have all the necessary components for QEMU, I suggest visiting [archlinux.QEMU https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU and installing the required dependencies. After that, you should rebuild QEMU, making sure to include the `--enable-gtk` option when running the configure command. This will allow you to confirm that the necessary dependencies have been successfully installed.
2. Or you can simply remove QEMU you have and INSTALL `qemu-full` which will bring all the dependencies required.

Answer (score 0):

first
according to what @Chan Kim said, but there is nothing about `qemu-system-i386` and `qemu-system-x86_64` in `qemu/bin`.

then
run `./configure --prefix=/data/local/qemu --target-list=i386-softmmu,arm-softmmu,x86_64-softmmu --disable-vnc --enable-sdl`, then I find all about qemu-system.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro but what i feel is normally, QEMU uses SDL to display the VGA output. With this option, you can have QEMU listen on VNC display display and redirect the VGA display over the VNC session.

Second solution may be installing libvirt
and adding to user group

`sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $USER`

`sudo systemctl enable libvirtd.service`

`sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service`